# regex to restrict only number in string field

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible using only regex to restrict number only in string string field?

For example :  123456 (not allowed) , 12Test (Allwed) , test (allowed), test#@12 (allowed)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code to match only numbers.
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(value, "^[0-9]*$");

you can also try using ^\d+$ or regex = new Regex("^[0-9]+$"); regex pattern.

Comment: Granted, the question is confusing, but the OP wants a regex to *exclude* the case of only numbers, i.e. "123456" should *not* be allowed, while something like "abc123" would be fine.

Comment: if(!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(value, "^[0-9]*$")) should work fine

Comment: Actually, that regex does nothing. As any string you throw at it will pass, including the case of all numbers.

Comment: Man, its still early here and regexes before coffee is apparently a no-go. Actually, that regex allows only numbers or an empty string, based on the inclusion of the beginning and end constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this non-consuming regex can help

```
[0-9]*(?=([a-zA-Z\W|_]+))
```

Answer (score 0):

Show the following in your `ViewSource`

```
data-val-regex-pattern="([a-zA-Z0-9 .&amp;amp;&amp;#39;-]+)"
```

Model Example:-

```
[StringLength(100)]
[Display(Description = "Name")]
[RegularExpression("([a-zA-Z0-9 .&'-]+)", ErrorMessage = "Enter only alphabets and numbers of Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

ViewSource:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Name must be a string with a maximum length of 100." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-regex="Enter only alphabets and numbers of Name" data-val-regex-pattern="([a-zA-Z0-9 .&amp;amp;&amp;#39;-]+)" id="Name " maxlength="100" name="Name " type="text" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

this pattern should do it to restrict numbers only

```
^(?=.*[^0-9\r\n]).*$
```

a lookahead to see non-digit in multi-line fields or

```
^(?=.*[^0-9]).*$
```

in single line fields